# using mutt to send 2 files

Tags: email, mutt

In the following example, I can use comma to send the same message to 2 recipients. But I can not use comma to send 2 files.

```
echo "Here is the file you requested" | mutt -s "attaching file" -a one.txt -- me@company.com,you@company.com
```

How do I send the second.txt file in the same command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo "Here is the file you requested" | mutt -s "attaching file" -a one.txt -a two.txt -- me@company.com,you@company.com
```

Should work. A lot more work for 10-20 files though.

Answer (score 6):

As said in mutt manual (version 1.5.21).

> -a file [...]
>   Attach a file to your message using MIME.  When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g.

`mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1` or `mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2`

> The -a option must  be  placed at the end of command line options.

So this will be ok:

```
echo "Here is the file you requested" | mutt -s "attaching file" -a one.txt second.txt -- me@company.com,you@company.com
```

Comment: which mutt version should I use? I tried the above command but only the first file is being sent. Mutt 1.4.2.2i (2006-07-14)

Comment: @shantanuo I use 1.5.21. Please add your version to the question.